# Sinatra not passing header with redirect

Tags: redirect, header, sinatra, rack

I have a simple Sinatra proxy, which when an endpoint is called, will redirect to another endpoint on the same Sinatra proxy.

When I make a request with a header, the proxy doesn't seem to pass this header through to the second endpoint when the request redirects in the first. This is my code:

```
    get '/first' do 
        # get the header from the request
      username = env['HTTP_USERNAME'] 
        # set the header for the response
      response['username'] = username 
      redirect '/second'
    end

    get '/second' do 
        # This doesn't exist when redirected from /first
    puts env['HTTP_USERNAME']

        # Here is a list of all headers
      env.each_key do |key|
        puts "KEY: #{key}  VALUE: #{env[key]}" unless key.nil?
      end

      "DONE"
    end
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is intentionally. `redirect` triggers an HTTP redirect, a new request will be fired. Also, passing on `env` values is done via modifying `env`, not `response`.

The main question is, what do you mean by header? Request header or response header? From your example I figure you mean request header, therefore `response['username'] = username` should be `request.env['username'] = username`. You could then replace `redirect '/second'` with `request.path_info = '/second'; pass` to do some sort of internal redirect. If you don't pass the value on to another Rack middleware/endpoint, you could also store the user name in an instance variable.

```
get '/first' do
  request.path_info = '/second'
  pass
end

get '/second' do
  puts request.env['HTTP_USERNAME']
  "DONE"
end
```

Comment: Thanks Konstantin - that was just what I was looking for. I clean forgot I could use the pass method. Cheers.